# Intel HD 530 Drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with my i3-6100 using integrated HD 530 graphics.  Works fine.  My question is should I install intel graphics stack release 2016 Q2 (https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2016q2-intel-graphics-stack-release)?  Just wondering if it would give me some options to customize my GPU settings or improve performance.  Sorry about the noob questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you should not. 16.04 ships with Kernel 4.4, the download you linked to is for 4.6. [Intel Graphics for Linux Version 1.4.0](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.4.0) would be correct but:

> - Ubuntu 16.04 - The Graphic Stack (i915) is up to date

Answer (score 4):

No, if it's a newer version at all it's only slightly newer. Intel's graphics drivers are open-source and use the Mesa OpenGL implementation, so they are included by default in Ubuntu. If you want a "bleeding-edge" development version, you may want to check out adding the [Oibaf](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) or [Padoka](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa) PPAs.

However, I would say, **"if it ain't broke, don't fix it."**